# Node 10 fails to install dependencies listed in package.json

Tags: node.js, dependencies, installation, package.json

Key points:

1. Requirement: package to be installed `npm install -g` (as multiple applications and background/batch processes will need it)
2. The package is part of a (currently public) organization and currently available as: `@asux.org/cli-npm`.
    It has 2 popular dependencies: "chalk" and "commander"

The problem:
 1. `npm install -g @asux.org/cli-npm` does NOT automatically do a `npm install -g <dependencies..>`
 2. it **actually** puts the dependencies under `(npm root -g)/@asux.org/cli-npm/node_modules`
 3. Within my code, `require("commander")` fails with the obvious error.
I even tried to test it manually within command line `node`.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'commander'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

My Workaround involves doing 2 steps:
1. Manually install dependencies after installing the package.  Silly!  Why bother with specifying dependencies in package.json, when using something called "Node Package **Manager**"!
2. Manually go around setting `export NODE_PATH=(npm root -g)` (FYI: can't show backticks in here).

FYI: Install and Un-install works cleanly.

QUESTIONS:

1. Is the ***ONLY*** "right" way .. to bundle everything (incl. dependencies) together? If so, any pointers?
2. Any other "right" way to **automatically** install all dependencies?
3. What is the right way to install Node+NPM, so that I do Not have to do something so fundamentally & foundationally basic like: `export NODE_PATH=(npm root -g)`?   (FYI: can't show backticks in here).

Here's the package.json

```
{
    "name": "@asux.org/cli-npm",
    "version": "1.9.0",

    "private": false,

    "publishConfig": {
        "access": "public",
        "tag": "latest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "chalk": "*",
        "commander": "2.20.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=10.2.2"
    },
..
```

FYI: The "DEFAULT" `npm root -g` produces (within the `/tmp` current working folder):

```
> module.paths
[ '/private/tmp/repl/node_modules',
  '/private/tmp/node_modules',
  '/private/node_modules',
  '/node_modules',
  '/Users/Sarma/.node_modules',
  '/Users/Sarma/.node_libraries',
  '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.2.1/lib/node' ]
```

I hope it's something really really stupid that I am doing.. .. cuz, otherwise it means that the entire package.json/npm MECHANISM is too stupid for anyone to explain to others, as to what the heck is going on.

Comment: I'd say it's not really common to use global dependencies in this way. I would probably install the dependency within each program that needs it.

Comment: 1. No you should not need to "bundle" the dependencies. 2: The dependencies are installed as expected. If you also need commander, couldn't you just do a "npm i commander -g" as well? 3: Of course NODE_PATH will need to be set. NODE_PATH is used to tell node where to look for modules.

Comment: 1) I could create a new script that lists all the "npm install -g" commands and ship that around.   Or, a  more enterprise-grade Package manager (like Maven) will read the dependencies and downloads all of them (if the right flags are provided).

Comment: 2) I need to run a FIXED unchanging command on each machine with Node?  Huh!?  What value exists .. if Node/NVM installation will NOT do that automatically for me?!
FYI: The fixed unchanging command being:  export NODE_PATH=`npm root -g`

Comment: 2) I need to run a FIXED unchanging command on each machine with Node?  Huh!?  What value exists .. if Node/NVM installation will NOT do that automatically for me (lets say: I provide a '-g' option during installation)?!
FYI: The fixed unchanging command being:  export NODE_PATH=`npm root -g`
I'm getting the feeling that '-g' is pariah/not-well-supported.  Documentation should just say that (or list scenarios to use it in).

Comment: Why do you need it to be installed globally?

Comment: For running tools as batch jobs, have to install for all the userids that batch-jobs run under.If install is mistakenly Not done in the root folder, its Not available for all the sub-projects.  Havent found a way to force install under ~/.node_modules or ~/node_modules.